# Find the solution of the following differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have to solve the following differential equation:

$$ x'-\frac{nx}{t+1}=e^t\left(t+1\right)$$

Here are the steps I have followed for the solution of this equation:

$$ x'-\frac{nx}{t+1}=0$$

$$x'=\frac{nx}{t+1}\ \ 
\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{nx}{t+1} \ \
\frac{dx}{nx}=\frac{dt}{t+1} \ \
\frac{1}{n}\int \frac{dx}{x}=\int \frac{d\left(t+1\right)}{t+1}  \ \
\frac{1}{n}\ln x=\ln\left|t+1\right|+lnc$$

$$ \ln x=n\ln\left|t+1\right|+n\ln c$$ 
$$\ln x-n\ln c=n\ln\left|t+1\right|$$
$$\ln x-\ln c^n=n\cdot ln\left|t+1\right|$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{x}{c^n}\right)=n\cdot \ln\left|t+1\right|$$
$$\frac{x}{c^n}=e^{n\ln\left|t+1\right|}$$

$$ x=c^n\cdot e^{n\ln\left|t+1\right|}$$

$$ x=\left[c\left(t\right)\right]^n\cdot e^{n\ln\left|t+1\right|} $$

The next step is to find the derivative of $x$. Can someone help me find it?

Comment: I don't know what an integrating factor is

Comment: I have to follow specific steps, and the next one is finding the derivative of x. Thanks for the website anyway!

Answer (score 1):

$$x'-\frac{nx}{t+1}=e^t\left(t+1\right)$$
I agree with your transitional result : $x=(c(x))^n e^{n\ln|t+1|}$ which can be more simply writen :
$$x=C(x) (t+1)^n$$
where $C(x)=(c(x))^n$
$$x'=C'(t+1)^n+nC(t+1)^{n-1}$$
$$C'(t+1)^n+Cn(t+1)^{n-1}-\frac{n}{t+1}C (t+1)^n=e^t\left(t+1\right)$$
$$C'(t+1)^n=e^t\left(t+1\right)$$
$$C'=e^t\left(t+1\right)^{1-n}$$
$$C(t)=\int e^t\left(t+1\right)^{1-n}dt$$
$$x(t)=(t+1)^n \int e^t\left(t+1\right)^{1-n}dt$$
Don't forget the constant to add to the undefined integral.
You can let the result on this form. If not, it would require a special function either the Exponential Integral or the Incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: $C$ is a function of $t$

Comment: Yes, of course. The typo is corrected.